# Changing the background color of a captured image from camera to white

Tags: ios, image, background-color

I am working on a app in which user captures some images. and than he will change the background color to white. Its same as how FotoFuze.org does. I want to know how to change the background color to white without losing the object data.

For this i go through some of the things like detecting the background color. and editing the pixels whose color is background color to transparent. 
But this causing  problems if the image itself has some part colored as the background color.

So please suggest me the right way to accomplish this.

[image: original image]
[image: modified image]

Comment: please try this solution may be it will helpfull to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998097/ios-how-to-mask-the-image-background-color

Comment: @sateesh did you found any solution ?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have an idea, but it's based on Machine learning.

Comment: [https://github.com/darkcl/Background-Removal-Example]
use this for remove background color.